# angularJS $http datetime is changed

Tags: angularjs

I use `AngularJS` for my appl and also the `$http- provider`. 
I have a problem with the dateTime. I create da date with javaScript (`var date = new Date() e.g. 2016-03-09 00:00`) and if I will send this date (in object ParameterObject) to backend over `$http` one hour is subtract (2016-03-08 23:00+01:00). I will prevent this. Does anyone know how, is there e.g. a flag for `$http`?

```
return $http.post(baseURL + '/restServiceURL/', ParameterObject).success(function(data) {...
```

Comment: Timezone difference between the server and your local machine?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the following code to your js:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function () { return this.toLocaleString(); }
```

Comment: Is this a global setting in my javascript?

Comment: yes, it is! you can add your code and then have a try!